# Can we upload jar file in jenkins directly or we have to first upload jar file to git and add repo link in jenkins?

Tags: java, jenkins, jar, devops

I need to execute a standalone jar file with command line parameters from jenkins. Can I upload the jar file directly to jenkins or I have to first upload the jar file to github and then give the repo link on jenkins to run it. Also, from that entire jar file, I just want one of the .java class or files to be run in jenkins so I will use the "execute shell" in jenkins to give the command to run, right? I am looking for the best approach. Also, If I want to provide password+some configurable variables used in my code as command line arguments , should I provide them as "parameters" in jenkins while configuring?

I am trying to find the best way from start to end to execute a jar file from jenkins .

Comment: Committing jar or any derived artifacts (eg: .class , generate source, etc.)is considered bad practice and should be avoided. Check in the .Java, pull the repo, build the .class and run it. Or store the jar/class somewhere else and call it (full path).  All depends on your needs and setup.

Answer (score -1):

there is no better option to upload JAR directly , either you can upload in any repo and access through the link ,else you can keep the jar file in the local workspace of the system where Jenkins is installed.

Also for the variables like password and other configuration either you can add them as a parameter or you can create a .properties file in the repo and store all your variables data and values in that. Before building the project inject environment properties and give the path of properties file.

Comment: NO harm EVER came from checking in passwords into a repo, right? That is an egregiously bad suggestion, worse that checking in artifacts!